# How to add dynamic input values to the local state for retrieval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, multidimensional-array, react-state-management

I have a React Native form that allows me to add an `Input` UI in the form, by clicking a button with this function. This allow me to generate it on the fly. The code for that is this.

```
addClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ values: [...prevState.values, ""] }));
    console.log(this.values[0].name);
}
```

That part works well, but I'm having a problem extracting the data from the dynamic inputs, and add it to an array. So far I have tried this

```
setVal = value => {
    const values = this.state.values[0];
    if (values[0].name === "" || values[0].description === "") return;

    [...this.state.values, value];

    this.setState(values);
    console.log(values);
};
```

How do I organize my states properly so that I can add as many inputs I need, and when I'm finished, I can update the state, and access the new data in my list component?

How do I update my state to the new Array? at the moment, `this.state` only shows the initial state set at the top.

I'm missing a few things

Please take a look at the full code sandbox [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nwnnr0mq1p?fontsize=14) so you can see:

Comment: At a first glance at your code sandbox, I couldn't type into the input fields.  Could you please recreate your issue in a code snippet so we can help you and future users with a similar issue?

Comment: Hello @larz, thank you for that, I have updated the sandbox so that at first glance the inputs are editable.

Answer (score 0):

See...your created isssue is not so obvious we need to see where you call setVal() function but....

i think you will be more comfortable if you render your `<input/>` s directly from your state array, not from `const x = []` variant. because it seems like you want a dynamic view and in such a cases you will need to bind your loop quantity from state. so:

```
this.state = {
  x: [0,1,2,3,4]
}
```

and inside your render :

```
   {this.state.x.map(x => {
                return (
                  <TextInput
                    placeholder={`name${x}`}
                    value={values[x.toString()]}
                    handleBlur={() => handleBlur(x.toString())}
                    onChangeText={handleChange(x.toString())}
                    style={styles.input}
                  />
                );
              })}
```